# Ajax calenderextender SelectedDate value is always null.

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, ajaxcontroltoolkit

i have run into a problem where I have textbox with a calenderextender from ajaxtoolkit. I would like to retrieve the value the user puts in. This is how my code looks like

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtValidFrom" runat="server" TextMode="DateTime" AutoPostBack="true" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtValidTo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="exValidFrom" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtValidFrom" FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" Format="dd/MM/yyyy"></ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="exValidTo" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtValidTo" FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" Format="dd/MM/yyyy">
</ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
```

And my code behind:

```
logg.ValidFrom = exValidFrom.SelectedDate;
logg.ValidTo = exValidTo.SelectedDate;
```

Where ValidFrom and ValidTo are DateTime? variables. No matter what the user presses i always get null as value. I have tried to take the text direct from the textbox using

```
logg.ValidFrom = System.Convert.ToDateTime(txtValidFrom.Text);
logg.ValidTo = System.Convert.ToDateTime(txtValidTo.Text);
```

But i get the error

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried to see which value the CalendarExtender  sets when the user selects a date? It looks like it is not setting the textboxes date. Maybe you can assign `$('#txtValidFrom').val([whateverselectedwhereeverselected])` on select of the CalenderExtender?

Comment: How do i assign that? The textbox is filled with the selecteddate. Is there any other way to see what the calenderextender sets? @biseibutsu

Comment: I meant to say see if the textbox value is set from the browser developer console, you can set the value if it is not setting with Javascript.

Comment: And how do i set that? @biseibutsu

Comment: I don't know where you see the value, so I am not sure exactly? But for example if you find the value you want the textbox to be set, you can do `$('[id*=txtValidFrom]').val(value);` obviously you need to include jquery for that and I can not say where to get value from, because you haven't shared the rendered html.

Comment: I am a little bit confused. The code behind is C# so i'm not familiar with Jquery or javascript... @biseibutsu

Comment: Maybe you should check the documentation for CalenderExtender then, I don't know which property will give you the value.